# Makefile giving error

Tags: compiling, 15.10, c, makefile

I recently started learning C language on Ubuntu 15.10 .Today I learned about Makefile from http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html .But the problem is I keep on getting error

> > bharat@ratcoder:~/Programing/C$ make
> >     Makefile:4: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

I know I have to use Tab key instead of spaces and I am using the Tab key,But when using Tab does not solve my problem I tried googling and use

> > :%s/^[ ]+/^I/

this in vim as advised here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125757/error-while-executing-make-commad-in-ubuntu-terminal. But still I get the same error as above,so someone please help me where I am wrong or what should I do.I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: pls provide the full output when you run make command, with the single line it is difficult to understand where the problem occurs.

Comment: My makefile is same as in the link above http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex2.html and the complete command >>bharat@ratcoder:~/Programing/C$ make
Makefile:4: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

Comment: Unless you're familiar ith `vim` I'd recommend not trying to use a regex replacement - there's only one line, just open Makefile in a "normal" editor,delete the spaces and type a tab. FWIW the expression you found looks a little off to me: it needs to be `\+` instead of just `+`, and don't forget `^I` isn't a literal `^I` (it needs to be *composed* using Ctrl-V-TAB)

Comment: @steeldriver which editor should be used?I have vim,sublime text2 and of course gedit.

Comment: You can use any editor you like - Makefiles are plain text

Comment: @steeldriver I think u don't understand the problem.I have used Tab key in Makefile while making Makefile in gedit but the error I mentioned above keeps coming.

Comment: Have you configured gedit to insert spaces instead of tabs? Look under the Edit menu --> Preferences --> Editor --> Tab Stops. BTW your command should be either `make -f Makefile` or just `make` **not** `make Makefile`

Comment: @steeldriver my command is make ,rest is the error I keep getting and thnx for settings advice,this solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing the settings in gedit solved the problem.

> > Edit menu --> Preferences --> Editor --> Tab Stops

and uncheck

> > insert spaces instead of tab